# Can't send/receive a header with axios and python

Tags: python, reactjs, axios

I`m trying to send custom headers in a post request with axios in the following way:

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();

    console.log(token);
    const header = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    };
    const body = {
      source: "website",
      user_id: user.sub,
      message_category: "crypto",
      message_text: data,
    };
    console.log(body);

    axios
      .post(serverUrl + "messages/post_message", body, header)
      .then((res) => {
        // setPosts(res.data.messages);
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

But in my python cherrypy server I`m not getting the custom headers at all. although I do receive it in Acess-Control-Request-Headers as titles without the data.

debugging: auth = cherrypy.request.headers in python:
[image]

PS: Sending headers via postman works normally.

Comment: Did you try writing header = { content }, instead of header = { headers: { content } }?

Comment: @YungHK Yes. that way it doesnt show up even in the Access-Control-Request-Headers

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your API is working correctly (you might recheck that as well). See if this works for you:

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
  
  const options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    },
    body: {
      source: "website",
      user_id: user.sub,
      message_category: "crypto",
      message_text: data,
    }
  };

  axios
    .post(serverUrl + "messages/post_message", options)
    .then((res) => {
      // setPosts(res.data.messages);
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // handle error
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: same thing... what could go wrong in the API? If I am receiving the header with postman